# Scanner.findWithinHorizon() fails on multiline matches

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex that is being used to parse log files.

`(^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} ((?:WARNING)|(?:ERROR)|(?:DEBUG)|(?:INFO)))(.*(?!\1))`

Im using findWithinHorizon to split the file into its entries.

It works on all lines except when the log entry is more than one line, then it matches to just the first line. Is there a way to enable multiline matching? I'm using

```java
Pattern.compile(myPattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

now and it doesn't seem to work.

```java
 public static List<LogToken> tokenize(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner logReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile(_logEntryMarker,Pattern.MULTILINE);

        while (logReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String entry = logReader.findWithinHorizon(linePattern, 0);
            log.debug("Entry:" + entry);
            logReader.nextLine();
        }
....
```

Example log

```
2020-06-03 12:42:49,311 DEBUG - __init__.py:24 - Downloading https://example.com/432fa72661a80e01d68aaafc285c7c65190f4add24b2beee7961df19b47f9c19
2020-06-03 12:42:49,430 DEBUG - __init__.py:26 - Saved https://example.com/432fa72661a80e01d68aaafc285c7c65190f4add24b2beee7961df19b47f9c19 to /tmp/tmpwur9pw14
2020-06-03 12:42:52,653 WARNING - dr.py:974 - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/insights/core/dr.py", line 962, in run
result = DELEGATES[component].process(broker)
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/insights/core/dr.py", line 681, in process
return self.invoke(broker)
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/insights/core/plugins.py", line 64, in invoke
return super(PluginType, self).invoke(broker)
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/insights/core/dr.py", line 661, in invoke
return self.component(*args)
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccx_ocp_core/models/nodes.py", line 108, in Nodes
int(node.q.status.capacity.memory.value.split("Ki")[0]) / (1000 * 1000), 2
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

2020-06-03 12:42:52,757 INFO - payload_tracker_watcher.py:66 - Payload Tracker update successfully sent: {anonymized} processing
2020-06-03 12:42:52,759 DEBUG - kafka_publisher.py:74 - Sending response to the ccx.ocp.results topic.
```

There should be 5 total entries. The third entry should contain the python traceback.

Comment: I don't know Java but wonder if you don't need `Pattern.DOTALL` (or `(?s)`) so that the dot will match newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cary Swoveland had the correct answer

Using Pattern.DOTALL solved the problem